# How to use tfa.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention with tf.keras functional API?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, attention-model

I want to use [`tfa.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/BahdanauAttention) with functional API of `tf.keras`. I have looked at the example given at [tensorflow/nmt/attention_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/attention_model.py). But I couldn't figure out how to use it with `tf.keras`'s functional API.

So I would like to use `tfa.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention` for a lipreading task, something like this:

```py
    # Using tf.keras functional API
    encoder_out = a tensor of shape (batch_size, time_steps, units)
    decoder_out = a tensor of shape (batch_size, time_steps, units)
    attn_out = attention_mechanism()(encoder_out, decoder_out)  # Need help figuring this out
```

Thanks in advance.